# How to query a json date range on Django REST?

Tags: json, django, charts, django-rest-framework, view

How to query a JSON Date Range on Django REST?

I have a graph on my frontend UI, I have an option which date to display. (day/week/month/year) and fetch it from an API.

How to do it? like if the user click "day", the API will be like. `api/sample_data/current_day.` or if "week" then `api/sample_data/current_week`.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you make your BE endpoints use date (or datetime) range filters.
For example:
`api/sample_data/?date_after=2021-01-10&date_before=2021-01-18`. And make FE resolve `current_day`, `current_week` or anything else into `date_after` and `date_before` dates.

For filtering your data I would suggest you use [django-filter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io). Here is part of the docs on how to integrate it into DRF: [django-filter DRF integration](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/guide/rest_framework.html). The exact filter you should use is [DateFromToRangeFilter](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/stable/ref/filters.html?highlight=DateFromToRangeFilter#datefromtorangefilter).